# How to convert a xarray MFdataset into multiple geotiffs? Trying two methods and failing so far

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-xarray, netcdf4, rasterio

I am trying to convert multiple NetCDF4 files to GeoTIFF rasters while downsampling the data from daily frequency to monthly frequency (ignoring NaNs). Unfortunately, I get errors when I get to the step when I want to write the data into geotiffs.

It was easy to open and downsample files using xarray (awesome functionalities if compared to R, which is what I am used to working with) keeping just one variable, as I wanted and calculating monthly means from daily values but, I got stuck trying to export/convert my results into multiple *.tif files.

Even tried converting it to multiple NetCDF3 files, since I can convert those to geotiff easily, but also failed.

Input data are 4018 ESA soil moisture ".nc4" files in daily frequency, covering the whole globe but incomplete at each step (only swaths for each day are filled with data, the rest is empty/NA), so I want to ignore NaNs for calculating the monthly means.

In total, these 4018 days tally up to 132 months (11 years) and my xarray dataset produced from the code below, seems to show that, as expected.

```
import xarray as xr

# opening the files into an array

mfdataDIR = 'C:/full_path_here/*.nc'

DS = xr.open_mfdataset(mfdataDIR)


# downsampling it from daily to monthly means while keeping attributes and ignoring NAs 

monthly_data = DS.sm.resample(time="1M").mean(skipna= True, keep_attrs=True)
```

I got the following warning here: "Default reduction dimension will be changed to the grouped dimension after xarray 0.12. To silence this warning, pass dim=xarray.ALL_DIMS explicitly. skipna=skipna, allow_lazy=True, **kwargs)"
Not sure if it matters but results seem ok when I print the monthly_data xarray.

```
# Now, trying to convert to GeoTIFFs using Robin Wilson's rasterio_to_xarray (and vice-versa) script (full script can be found on link below).

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/path_to_py_script/')

import xarray_to_rasterio as xarrast

xarrast.xarray_to_rasterio_by_band(monthly_data, 'C:/path_here/%s.tif', dim= 'time')
```

Now I got this error: "IndexError: tuple index out of range" 
I think the mistake is in how I am trying to use it and not on the script although I can't see where.

The script made by Robin Wilson, which would be ideal for my objectives, was gotten here: https://github.com/robintw/XArrayAndRasterio/blob/master/rasterio_to_xarray.py

I see errors traced to line 84:

```
82  if len(xa.shape) == 2:
83        count = 1
84        height = xa.shape[0]
85        width = xa.shape[1]
86        band_indicies = 1
87   else:
```

and line 122:

```
122  xarray_to_rasterio(data, filename)
```

So, it seems my time dim, which I hoped would count as bands, are not what the script expects and so, it fails. And also I am messing up with "filename" parameter, apparently.

Don't know how... Can I use this script or modify it to do what I want?
(to save 132 ".tif" files corresponding to 132 levels of the time dim)

```
# Second option, not ideal but could still help me, if it hadn't also failed:


mDS = monthly_data.to_dataset()

paths = ['C:/path_here/%s.nc' ]
xr.save_mfdataset(mDS, paths, format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC')

got this error: "TypeError: save_mfdataset only supports writing Dataset objects, received type <class 'str'>"
```

I think my lack of python knowledge is hampering me as I keep getting errors in both procedures (xarray to GeoTIFF or xarrayDataset to NetCDF3 classic).

When I inspect the monthly_data I see what I expected: only the "sm" variable, all three dimensions and 132 time "values".

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi, I'm Robin Wilson, the author of the code you're trying to use. I'm a bit confused by the error - I can't quite see how it can happen, but obviously it has!
Can you include the output of `print(monthly_data)` and `print(monthly_data.shape)`, as that might help me debug the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and thank you for dropping by @robintw !
The output of print(monthly_data) is:
`<xarray.DataArray 'sm' (time: 132)>
dask.array<shape=(132,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1,)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2007-01-31 2007-02-28 ... 2017-12-31
Attributes:
    long_name:        Volumetric Soil Moisture
    units:            m3 m-3
    valid_range:      [0. 1.]
    _CoordinateAxes:  time lat lon`


while print(monthly_data.shape) produces:

`(132,)`

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the way I subsampled (downscalling) the array...